Is there any way to get DSolve to provide trivial solutions?
When trying to solve
  DSolve[{x''[t] + x'[t] == x[t] y[t], y''[t] == -x[t]  y[t]}, {x, y}, t]

Mathematica returns the input.
Two solutions (trivial) are
$$(x(t),y(t)) = (A + B e^{-t}, 0)~~ \mbox{or}~~ (0, A t + B)$$
Is there any way to coax these out of Mathematica?
I am running V14.0, Windows 10, x86.

Well, there is also simpler solution, $x=0,y=c_1$ but since Mathematica can't solve it to start with, then I am not sure how to ask it to give trivial solution can be made.

and ofcourse $x=0,y=0$ are also trivial solutions. One way to find these is just to try. If they satisfy the ode, then you are done.

I'd argue the definition of "trivial" is a bit vague? Can it be defined in a clearer way?

@xzczd the most common definition is that trivial solution to an ode or set of ode's should really be just the zero solution(s). It also has to be a solution that can be obtained from the general solution for some value of the constant of integration. Because it is possible to have $y=0$ as solution but not be trivial if it can't be obtained from the general solution. In this case it is singular solution.

One way, but I'm sorry I don't have time to explain. Maybe after finals.  Can delete if it's too obnoxious to have just code:
trivialDSolve[eqns_, vars_, t_Symbol] := 
 With[{trivialSolutions = 
    Cases[eqns, (v_Symbol)[t] == 0 :> v -> Function[t, 0]]},
  With[{remainingEquations = And @@ eqns /. trivialSolutions,
    newVars = vars /. trivialSolutions /. _Function -> Nothing},
   If[TrueQ@remainingEquations || newVars === {},
    trivialSolutions,
    Join[#, trivialSolutions] & /@ 
     DSolve[remainingEquations, newVars, t]
    ]
   ]];

ode = {x''[t] + x'[t] == x[t]  y[t], y''[t] == -x[t]   y[t]};
primesToIndex = {
   Derivative[n_][v_][t] :> v[n], v_[t] :> v[0]};
indexToPrimes = {v_[n_] :> Derivative[n][v][t]};
manifold = ode /. primesToIndex;
Reduce[{manifold, And @@ Or @@@ D[manifold, {{x[0], y[0]}}]} // Flatten
  , Join[Array[x, 3, 0], Array[y, 3, 0]]];
List @@ % /. indexToPrimes // Map[trivialDSolve[#, {x, y}, t] &]
(*
{{{y -> Function[{t}, C[1] + t  C[2]], x -> Function[t, 0]}},
 {{x -> Function[{t}, -E^-t  C[1] + C[2]], y -> Function[t, 0]}},
 {x -> Function[t, 0], y -> Function[t, 0]}}
*)


Interesting - but is the definition of trivialDSolve missing?
